# any sample app or code for sending data(String) from android app (application form) to local host?

Tags: android, localhost

I need a sample of very basic app in which 2-3 variables are passed to local host from an android app(containing application form).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read [Android Volley Tutorial - Making HTTP GET, POST, PUT, DELETE Requests](http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put)

Be careful, address of your local host from your adroid is : 10.0.2.2